# How to transform a directed Dataset into a Matrix with R

Tags: r, matrix, transformation

I have a Dataset in R which looks like this:

```
ID LinkedTo
1  Null
2  1
3  1
4  3
5  4
```

I want transform it into a Matrix which looks similar to this:

```
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option , is to modelize your directed dataset as a directed graph and extract adjacency matrix.

```
library(igraph)

dat <- read.table(text='ID LinkedTo
2  1
3  1
4  3
5  4',header=TRUE)

gg <- graph.data.frame(dat)
 as.matrix(get.adjacency(gg))
  2 3 4 5 1
2 0 0 0 0 1
3 0 0 0 0 1
4 0 1 0 0 0
5 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more convenient if you replace "Null" by NA in your dataset. Something like

```
i <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
    LinkedTo = c(NA, 1, 1, 3, 4)), 
    .Names = c("ID", "LinkedTo"),
    row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
i
#   ID LinkedTo
# 1  1       NA
# 2  2        1
# 3  3        1
# 4  4        3
# 5  5        4
```

Then you can do

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow(i), nrow(i))
m[i$ID + (i$LinkedTo - 1) * nrow(i)] <- 1
```

(It would work the same way if `i` was a matrix, but you would have to change `i$ID` and `i$LinkedTo` to `i[, 1]` and `i[, 2]` resp)

Answer (score 0):

you can start by replacing the null with zeros, i think . 
Then you can do a little for loop:

```
data.frame(id=1:5, pos=sample(1:5))->df
matrix(nrow=max(nrow(df)),ncol= max(df$id),data=0)->m
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  m[i,df$pos[i]]<-1
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @konvas `i` dataset

```
i[,2][is.na(i[,2])] <- 0
m <- matrix(0, nrow(i), nrow(i))
m[as.matrix(i)] <- 1
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    1    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

`table` should also work if you combine it with `factor`. (I say "should" because your conditions aren't clearly specified and your sample data are not reproducible.)

Using @konvas's "i" sample data, try:

```
> table(i$ID, factor(i$LinkedTo, 1:5))

    1 2 3 4 5
  1 0 0 0 0 0
  2 1 0 0 0 0
  3 1 0 0 0 0
  4 0 0 1 0 0
  5 0 0 0 1 0
```